# Why does Typescript not infer the type for a generic type guard although the IDE infers the type correctly?

Tags: typescript, generics, typeguards

`Hello, world!`

I am working with Typescript and Webstorm and I am trying to use a type guard, which does not seem to be totally correct.

This is an example to show what I want to achieve. It is also [linked in a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdTqAhqSBTANgBzQJ1AC4D2oAZtAHYAmh6oAtkgQMYwUDmozGSs84ATxwAoSgTykkzNFyK5caWFiLVY4IgB4A0jz4A+UAG8AvsOEhQAQQoIK43JOlk5yUFh6VQAKyQA3Xsy40FgEoEQARl5ozASidhJSMgDq0ABeSLhUAApEXiRoAB7iqrLyisqq6hoASmhIGCnpmXqGwqDtoBRI9GgA-ABcoLAEQRwA3MKm5mCWoFR40P7hGDJI4cO4UqHcvPDCaxtbXLrwljHQKkZmHW4ScvRnBBcUABQAlFc3N8wqsEQrADoMER2C8AOQAcSIAEIwW8JjcplMLLMdnxQAB3GCsBD0dxoHp2eAEOjuJCeMQJJxIajIDB-WzoIIEeAoHokohUYRo+C1eqNDI0QrFKinc6XaB4laElmgAWZHJ5T4dLo9QYbSjsBEdNodHAOe4AWSQ7GgzHeyq+sgof0BwNBYMAFORw7XtUzIsBQRCISA0qgrGjhASEISKQLBUK8UCFHAxNBc0gAVwo4psPB6xtNzFAFtauvaPxtoV98gEgz5DTSgtAAF5OmgMaAK-KqO9XagMrgBAD9aQjSazW32hYfmUYvmO6We3dcA9U0PQCO5Apx9cOoXhpOu4qiIMWzva0ZjO2S9vckRpwbZ5nBx8LHhcHJBmDe-2s2C5kRFJ0iKFCnBQgAWgMUcV1iG5TwEHdLz7WdHmeC173kJ9QBfGc5yeFQPyoL94AoX9owKADQGA0owLMKYzAsAA5IhGyZGRED+dk2E4fDQgxOQAGtNWQeAY2icQE2TVNQAUeob3NRgBHCNA9yrBVz1AAAfJs6krJoaA+PMbmgUgXjgHRdgAeUiQSXmk2S3m0tcrQsJJIGDRASSYZAbAfORegnG5LLQGC31vdsfKQGS-NfOD53hbz11+DiFKoct1JbQ9fImaLhzABzgxw792NoGQCFDUB2ETatfWoFZ8q4XgCC8q0C1ivjkrrXy+LU-l4rGUB0qa+L-OvAdzSi+res0-qMIQt4JyRMxzAAKjaABJYrE0UYkYGJIqSurCg0HjeBmJkeg5COwbCBITjcC4sjBIwAQ2igGQMTQaBMloTU9zQdZiFnHMMWgDlE1CQQcFgcMQlAHgOFK9gZFgPBfDNOG0AIJ4OCGFGprE6IQQoNJvxJAqitA277rm4BhCTFNMJsQyTlMqIYg0A9hTQEoSaUFRRSqGkBD0AwXgiLxBh3LGOkGIWEHgFmijZ0Ubs5ypNEoUg8FAIz9FAXp1ZOUBBmTLj8IxGxWhGhQCETXAbEKnAiFIHNJajXm3gBWA-BkGtPdQqnUzBCZjCAA).

```js
// This is a helper to find the matching class Type
interface correspondsTo<Klass> {}

// An interface for a plain javascript object
interface WizardPojo extends correspondsTo<RealWizard>{
    name?: string;
}

// A derivable abstract class 
abstract class Action {

    performAction() {
        console.log('Go!');
    }

}

// A class which implements the plain interface and also inherits a method
class RealWizard extends Action implements WizardPojo {
    name: string;
    
    performMagic() {
        console.log('✨');
    }
}

// This is handled by typescript as expected
function lameMagic () {

    const harry: RealWizard = new RealWizard();
    harry.performMagic();  // correct
    harry.performAction();  // correct


    const harryPojo: WizardPojo = {};
    harryPojo.performMagic() // error: 'performMagic' does not exist -> correct
    harryPojo.performAction() // error: 'performAction' does not exist -> correct

}



// Now here is something not working as expected
function realMagic(maybe: WizardPojo | RealWizard ) {

    if(isKlassObject(maybe)) {

        // Why is that an error?
        maybe.performMagic();
        maybe.performAction();
        const wizard: RealWizard = maybe;

        // Why does not the type guard handle the cast?
        const asWizard = maybe as RealWizard; 
        asWizard.performMagic();
        asWizard.performAction()
    }

}


/*
 I guess this type guard needs some more magic to work correctly
 The weird thing: Webstorm (without Typescript language service setting set)
 recognizes the type correctly
*/
function isKlassObject<Pojo extends correspondsTo<any>> (obj: Pojo)
    : obj is Pojo extends correspondsTo<infer Klass> ? Klass : unknown {
        return typeof (obj as any).save === 'function';
}
```

The thing is: When I use Webstorm without the 'Typescript language service' activated, the type guard results in the correct type. However, when I try to convert the code, `tsc` throws an error and I don't know why.

In my project I have a lot of those Pojo interfaces and classes which are automatically generated in `d.ts` files and I want to use just one generic type guard function to determine if a Pojo is a Klass object. And I want to avoid explicit type cast with `as`.

It is important to me to use both, Pojo interfaces and Klass types.

Do you have an idea, how to fix this type guard problem?

Comment: I think the problem here comes from the fact that you have a conditional type in your type guard. In the example you provide, I don't see any reason why the type guard couldn't just be `obj is SpecialActions`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I changed my example a little bit. Unfortunately it is not enough to return `obj is SpecialActions` since the `RealWizard` class also provides another method which should be accessable after calling `isKlassObject`

Comment: Then why not `obj is RealWizard`?

In any case, the point of type guards is to help the compiler when it's unable to determine the type of the object by itself, so using an inferred type here doesn't really make sense to me. In fact, the inferred type will always just be `WizardPojo | RealWizard` (how is the compiler supposed to determine when it's a `RealWizard` or not?).

Comment: `obj is RealWizard` also is not a good choice because in my project I don't only have `WizardPojo` and `RealWizard`, but also a lot of other interfaces/classes like `AnimalPojo` and `RealAnimal` or `BuildingPojo` and `RealBuilding` and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution** !

I can use the same technique like `sequelize` uses it in its typings for the [model attribute types](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/5924be52152232fbd7a925d599c31cac9f90dc6d/types/lib/model.d.ts#L1566).

The trick is to assign the generic `Klass` type to a fake property in the `correspondsTo` interface.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdTqAhqSBTANgBzQJ1AC4D2oAZtAHYAmh6oAtkgQMYwUDmozGSs84ATxwAoSgTykkzNFyK5caWFiLVY4IgB4A0jz4A%20UAG9hoU6BNngAKgtmroAIKgqAV3r0BoAG5Jc0JABGGDIEkEzORIoUAOQEoGgAHnBxKrQyCkgYoEQBAFZozAQAdLam9lCIiBRoaFS1oLAkgjiwzH5YccxIFAgUpHhphEIyzHIKhRielIMEw6DsLr5UReZmZcClGVQqk6AA%20hkYOrywAPwAXKDHfADcwgC%20wsIgoACqsCF0ru6eAAYHaEy11gv2QBAIfgCLnEhBIlH6%20FCIzGBTisxwoEAPBuASP3hKQXBRCtBUnBgQB5PKojQABSIuSIBgAFDlcpdafSAJSlS4shDwdkkRLiVSyeSKZSqdQaboCAynUACgDa0QBQN0sGiAF1QGy6SRjGs1goCC5cD10WgiKRQMy8sh4DKOUUcLhSHJ6A4iakALy%200DRfGEgjEmJ3R7PMAOHpiCRSGRu-AoLA8aa5JA%20VrtFKUwqiCjiV1x0AAdWgAC8lgL4glhVR4KMxUoVHWpQAlQEYUsV3BUPQGswUJD0NAXBoQyjsMNPF5OOp%20HxBGSBWAQqSddXmZerwpcDee4OpYylF0Jj1eiiMjlGUprUYURrBIoYIjsRnRADiRAAhNEOXc1uG4YzruJygAA7jArAIPQyZoMO%20bwEioDJkg0wxoW0jINQyAYI0vToH4BAOgwaChEQVDCNwoHtpkXZLNWtbwPuIbQbB8FESW5aVnq15rIOw6XCufgcP%20ZjHhI7oALJIOw0DMJevGGqYd4PmgT4vm%20gAU5L%20ommI8QFgAERChEMGKwNA7CDiaCgOgo2QANaXGg0BIvgOx-HRPYCr8eIEueyF6tJsnyYwAgBGglyeVQVZXkeazQKQjKkuqFL5IUjKheFHKxU8SmmC8UAhHMlR9HgCg0A24wEJMX5YrieUMEgYVqSeUkyXJl66YamUtRJuBngeF5-qUgHTmARQTdkiJ0OhHz%20RaoC-FFVYAD6gDRnZcT2PmBv5hxBR1PWRVt0U8WtG1RaAOWlAlSWwOSOYEBlTVZddDUFXQC0lQi5WilVNV1TeZg9c6fX0Ad8nDQ1IOtf1zEqJ1I1PI8QA)

```js
// This is a helper to find the matching class Type
interface correspondsTo<Klass> {
    
    /*
     * A dummy variable that doesn't exist on the real object.
     * This is needed so Typescript can infer the type correctly in the type guard. 
     */
    readonly _realKlass?: Klass;
}

// Use the dummy `_realKlass` attribute to infer the correct type 
function isKlassObject<Pojo> (obj: Pojo)
    : obj is Pojo extends correspondsTo<any> ? Pojo['_realKlass'] : Pojo {
        return typeof (obj as any).performAction === 'function';
}

// An interface for a plain javascript object
interface WizardPojo extends correspondsTo<RealWizard>{
    name?: string;
}

// A derivable abstract class 
abstract class Action {

    performAction() {
        console.log('Go!');
    }

}

// A class which implements the plain interface and also inherits a method
class RealWizard extends Action implements WizardPojo {
    name: string;
    
    performMagic() {
        console.log('✨');
    }
}

// both type signatures are ok: either only `WizardPojo`
function pojoMagic(maybe: WizardPojo ) {

    if(isKlassObject(maybe)) {

        // The type is inferred correctly! 
        maybe.performMagic();
        maybe.performAction();
    }

}

// ... or the intersection type `WizardPojo | RealWizard`
function realMagic(maybe: WizardPojo | RealWizard ) {

    if(isKlassObject(maybe)) {

        // The type is inferred correctly! 
        maybe.performMagic();
        maybe.performAction();
    }

}
```